# How to Jquery animate CSS left value to width of element?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I need to move an absolute div relative to its parent using the Jquery animate function. How do I limit a CSS object literal left += -600px so that the left positioning stops when it reaches the end of the width? In other words I want to limit the left positioning of the element so that it doesn't keep moving off the page and out of view. Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you know the pixel position of the left edge of the parent?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).animate({'left': '-'+$(this).parent().width()}, [time in ms]);
```

Or if you meant the elements own width:

```
$(this).animate({'left': '-'+$(this).width()}, [time in ms]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery `animate`'s `step`-function to check at each step whether the element has reached the edge of the page and should be stopped. [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/n2QEs/5/) is a fiddle that demonstrates using the step function to stop the animation when a limit is reached.

```
 ...animate({left: '+=-600px'},
   {
     ... ,
     step: function(now, fx) {
       if (fx.now <= 0) { // If the current animation value is less than zero
         $(fx.elem).stop();
         $(fx.elem).style('left', '0');
       }
     }
     ...
   }   
 );
```

The step function gives you a nice way to control the animation step by step if necessary. Read [here](http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/03/01/the-jquery-animate-step-callback-function/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it lined up within the parent, you'll need to subtract the child width from the parent width, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var childWidth = $('#child').width();
var parWidth = $('#child').parents('#parent').width();
var offSet = parWidth - childWidth;

$('#child').animate({
    left: '+=' + offSet  
}, 1000);

});
```

Example HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
      I've been a bad child.  
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#parent {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;  
  position: relative;  
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;        
}
```

[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chippper/WSHLN/1/) for a demonstration.

Answer (score -1):

Well you didn't provide any code so my only guess is that you misunderstood how jQuery's animate function works. Actually jQuery's animate function does exactly what you want it to. It will increase the attributes of the element you want it to no more than you want it to. That is, it won't it keep moving it off the page and out of view unless you want it to. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) have a read how it works.